# Qt WebEngine for java?

Tags: java, qt, blink

Qt has launched the Qt WebEngine project to make blink available, can I use Qt Jambi to use the Qt WebEngine feature?

Answer (score 1):

Short answer: No.

First of all Qt WebEngine are not yet part of Qt, its not even in trunk (6.X).

Secondly Qt Jambi ain't even available for current versions of Qt, and unless something changes it will not be available for a version with Qt WebEngine.

In Java I would suggest that you check the JavaFX WebEngine out.